# How to delete markers from my own google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete markers from my own google maps, but my code didnt work and I don't know why. Would you like to help me? Thanks!

Data in function removeMarkers()  - markers.length, is stil empty, if I try to debug by console.log(markers.length);

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.8037633, 15.4749126)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('add-markers'), 'click', addMarkers);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('remove-markers'), 'click', removeMarkers);
}

function addMarkers() {

    var markerCluster;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-places.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var markers = [];
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    // icon: icon,
                    title: element.title
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                var details = element.name;

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, details);

            });
            markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
            });
        }
    });
}

function removeMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
initialize();
```

Function `addMarkers()` works well, but `removeMarkers()` not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a global variable as `var markers = [];` but you do not populate this when you get AJAX response back. What you do in `function addMarkers()` is populate the variable `markers` inside this function which is local to this function.

You will need to remove `var markers = [];` from `function addMarkers()` and instead use the global variable to populate markers from your AJAX response. Then you will be able to remove markers in removeMarkers function.

```
var markers = []; // this is global scope

function addMarkers(){
   var markers = [];  // remove this declaration in this function as it creates local scope


}

function removeMarkers(){
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
   }
   markers = []; // do not forget to set this empty
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But after this I found another problem. 

When I call
- addMarkers
- removeMarker
- addMarkers

Last call of addMarker return double amount of entries. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What is your another problem? You should really ask another question if you have a different problem. But i am happy to help.

Comment: Do you mean when you click addMarkers twice you have double entries?

Comment: No, first I call addMarkers, then I call removeMarkers and then I call addMarker. After this call it return twice entries (double counts of markers[])

Comment: It is due to the fact the the markers variable still has elements from the first `addMarker` call. You need to empty `markers` variable in `removeMarkers()` function after you have removed markers from the map.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the re-declaration of `markers` array. Your `removeMarkers` function does not know about the `markers` array you're populating inside your `success` callback.

```
var markers = [];

...

success: function(data) {
    var markers = []; // <- remove that redeclaration
```